# What is the purpose of jumping?

Tags: smite

I can jump! Hop! Hop! Why am I jumping? Am I dodging anything?

What is the purpose of arguing with gravity in this game?

(No, seriously, why can I jump and what purpose does it serve if any?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jumping is only there for fun. It does not increase movement speed, dodge abilities, jump over minions, etc.

In fact some would say jumping is bad because you are silenced (unable to do anything) while jumping.

It does make wandering around the jungle and getting to your lane slightly more entertaining. I mean who wouldn't laugh at Hades hopping around like a bunny on crack?

Comment: It's worth noting that on a gamepad controller (like when playing SMITE on Xbox One), jumping is assigned to pressing the thumbsticks. If you are a "clencher", that means you can unintentionally press jump in the heat of the action. As Rapitor pointed out, this can give you a disadvantage. You can turn off jumping in the options menu.

Comment: @MarcDingena Dingenga Don't forget that jumping as mercury is really bad as his passive doesn't get charged. Which results in him having less power on the next basic attack

Answer (score 3):

if u get stunned whilst in mid air from jumping you carry on going in that direction until you land