# Do you run slower backwards or sideways?

Tags: smite

I know that you move slower when using your basic attack.  I also know that **[jumping has no speed penalties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167684/what-is-the-purpose-of-jumping)**.  Is this the same when running backwards or sideways?

If true, what is the speed difference between each direction?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wiki](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Movement_penalty)

The Backpedal penalty is applied when walking backward. The Strafing penalty is applied for moving sideways. The Basic Attack penalty is applied while using basic attacks and for a short time afterwards. None of these penalties are shown in the movement speed counter. Some abilities such as Medusa's passive allow one or more of these penalties to be ignored.

According to community experiments:

```
Backpedal penalty = 40% reduced

Strafing penalty = 20% reduced

Ranged Basic Attack penalty = 50% reduced

Melee Basic Attack penalty = 35% reduced
```

Note: Movement speed reduction from the mentioned above sources can be compounded, but cannot exceed 50% reduction (e.g moving backwards while attacking will only reduce the player's movement speed by 50%).

Comment: also,  Medusa had no strafing penalty,  and half the back pedal penalty, as her [passive ability](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Medusa).

Comment: @Dpeif: There's a lot of exceptions. Isis and Chang'e both have exceptions to backpedaling, for example. Hastened Fatalis allows you to ignore the basic attack movement penalty. I'm sure there are others I'm just not remembering.